# Evitar regresar en php

Tags: php, javascript, html, php7

Tengo un sistema de cursos en donde el usuario lee cierta información de un tema, al final se evalúa al usuario con un examen de 10 preguntas al terminarlo y enviar el formulario con las respuestas se muestran la calificación de dicho examen.
El problema es que si el usuario regresa en el navegador se vuelve a mostrar el examen y puede hacerlo nuevamente, cosa que no quiero que suceda.

Espero que se pueda en php, si no tambien en JavaScript.

Comment: Usa sesiones o cookies, una vez que regresa lo rediriges

Comment: uso una sesion. Pero como sabria cuando regresa el usuario?

Answer (score 1):

La solucion es la siguiente:

Cuando inicia el test, creas un sesion PHP `session_start();`

En el resto de paginas pones un `if` que compruebe si existe o no sesion. Si no existe te redirige (`header("Location: http://www.domain.com/main-page.php");`) a la pagina principal o home.

Cuando llegues al final de test y el usuario haga click en el boton, aparte de mandar los resultados, destruyes la sesion. (`session_destroy();`)

Espero te sirva, suerte!